# Create xslt path dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following Problem: consider an xml like this:

```
<root>
    <bar>
        <status>456</status>
    </bar>
    <foo>
        <status>123</status>
    </foo>
    <tablename>foo</tablename>
</root>
```

How can I select the value of the node `status`, but only the one where the parent node equals the value of `tablename`?

Thanks very much!

Comment: if you downvote, please comment at least...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/root/*[local-name() = /root/tablename]/status`.

Comment: Nice! local-name() was exactly what I was looking for. Small additional question: why does it not work if i write it like ´root/*[local-name() = root/tablename]/status´? I thought this would be irrelevant for the root tag if I put a slash in front or not? Thanks!

Comment: Inside the predicate the context is the node selected to the left so a relative path `*[local-name() = root/tablename]` compares the local name with the grandchild `tablename` value of a `root` child element e.g. then your XML would need to have `<foo><root><tablename>foo</tablename></root><status>...</status></foo>`.